# Display / Show prompt text in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way to display the parameter prompt text in an SSRS report and not just the values?

We have a way to set the prompt text for a parameter based on customer specific text. In the report file the parameter (@Text)'s prompt is set to CustomerText123.

Then the customer can define what CustomerText123 is, and the report will replace the prompt text with the customer value when rendered. So, for example the prompt text for customer A can be Red and for customer B Blue.

In the report we display the values of the parameter by Parameters!Text.Label, but is there a way to also display the prompt text?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible, but then as you have to hard code the prompt into the parameter settings what is the issue with hardcoding the prompt elsewhere?

Comment: the prompt text is handled by .Net code that replaces the prompt text in the application where we have SSRS embedded. I guess we will just have to expand this function to replace specific text in textruns as well. Strange though that this is not available in the same way as Parameters!X.Value or label. Thanks for confirming there is no simple way though!